# Angular: Wait for an http call to finish in a second event

Tags: angularjs

I have  form with a submit method. Inside the form there is an input tag with a blur event handler. User types in some text into the input to look up item and clicks button to submit form. Below is some pseudocode:

```
MethodToGetData
{
 call http to get data and setup model objects
}

Blur Event Handler
{
  MethodToGetData
}

Submit Method
{
 MethodToGetData

 AddItem
}
```

The issue I am running into is if the user types in text and immediately clicks button to execute Submit, the blur event handler gets executed first and makes the http call. The submit method also makes the http call. I want to be able to execute the http call only once.

Any suggestions/thoughts on how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: use the `debounce` property of `ng-modelOptions`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a promise. Inject $q into your controller.

```
function controllerConstructor($q, someService) {
  var vm = this;
  var promise;

  vm.blur = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    promise = deferred.promise;
    someService.httpMethod().then(function() {
        deferred.resolve(dataToPass);
    });
  };

  vm.submit = function() {
    promise.then(
      function(dataThatWasPassed) {
        // Wont run until http call is finished
      }
    );
  };
}
```